# Collage cámara android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual debo tomar fotos y mostrarlas en un collague por medio de `Imagesview`.

Ya tengo en mi aplicación la manera de tomar la foto y la guardo en `ImageView`, solo que al momento de tomar otra foto borra la anterior.

Lo que quiero hacer es tomar una foto y ponerla en un `ImageView` y si tomo otra foto, la guardo en otro `ImageView` y que pueda visualizar las fotos tomadas en diferentes `ImageView`; cada una de manera de un collague.

Esta es mi xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.arturosv.camara.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hacer foto"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Este es mi main:

```
package com.example.arturosv.camara;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    ImageView foto1,foto2;
    ImageButton t;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        foto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void intent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            foto1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    private void intet() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arturo, son companeros de escuela?  se realizo una pregunta similar: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27167/crear-un-collage-de-fotos-en-android

Comment: Hola que tal , Mira no lo conozco pero tal vez este inscrito en mi misma universidad  pero en diferente campus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes definir cuantas imagenes quieres que el usuario pueda tomar, a cada ImageView que tengas en tu layout debes entregarle una ID y a medida que vaya tomando fotos tanto de la camara o seleccionando de su galeria vas reemplazando y pasando a la siguiente.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 />
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
 />
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView3"
 />
```

Activity

No escribi todo tu codigo, pero creo que el que te dejo es suficiente, aqui lo que hago es crear 3 imagenes (pueden ser las que tu quieras) y luego creo un arreglo de imagenes llamado collage. Inicializo cada imagen con su respectivo elemento del layout y luego los elementos del arreglo les seteo la que corresponde.

```
ImageView foto1,foto2, foto3;
ImageView[] collage= { foto1, foto2, foto3 };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    foto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    foto2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    foto3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    collage[0] = foto1;
    collage[1] = foto2;
    collage[2] = foto3;
}


@Override

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
         for (ImageView img : collage) {
            if(img.getDrawable()==null){
                img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                break;
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Aqui recorro el arreglo de imagenes collage, pregunto si el elemento de la iteración tiene imagen, de no ser asi, le cargo la que tomo con la camara y corto el loop, para asi no llenar las demas imagenes.

Comment: @Samu JM es un usuario nuevo y dejo un error que dice que le sale al usar el codigo de su respuesta, pero lo dejo como respuesta en esta pregunta, ya se le ha orientado mas o menos, pero creo que el no puede comentar, quizas le pueda echar una mano. Saludos

Comment: el error es el siguiente -> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {carlarsolutions.myapplication/carlarsolutions.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThrea.............`

Comment: Bueno el error hace referencia a un objeto null, si pueden dejar mas código podria ayudar mejor

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una lista. Para ello usa el RecyclerView. Lo que está ocurriendo es que siempre le estás indicando que la imagen que tomes, se pongan el el ImageView que tienes, por lo tanto se reemplaza.

Puedes crear una clase que se llame por ejemplo Fotos con un atributo String path;

Luego cuando tengas la lista y vayas a añadir la imagen, la guardas en el ArrayList que le envías al RecyclerView, pero en este caso estarías creando una nueva entrada y no sobreescribiendo el imageView.